# comparison between Drupal and GWT

Tags: drupal, gwt, drupal-modules

im building a website for learning .. and it have a live streaming session section on the website where users can watch a live session online.

so, i have two choices for the technology i must use which is GWT (Java) or Drupal (PHP) ??

looking for advices .. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If SEO is a concern, go drupal, if you're looking for pure javascript / web2.0 applications (like gmail), then GWT will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is a CMS, a Content Management System that allows you to build web sites quickly.
GWT is a toolkit that compile java into css/html/js and provides some widgets.

These are completely different technologies.

BTW, an gwt app well developped will not have SEO problems. Simply use the history handler and make your app crawlable for search engines.

Comment: Thnaks, but dose there is any module in Drupal can help me with the live streaming or i need to build it from basis ??

Comment: I don't know drupal, I'm a Gwt user. But I'm aware that there is many drupal plugins available. See http://drupal.org/project/Modules

Answer (score 0):

An analogy to your question would be

**"I am hungry, shall I eat apples or oranges ?"**

- First thing when you are hungry(in your case just learning), `eat something and fill your hunger`(go with a solution that keeps you happy.)
- Second thing you are trying to `compare apples and oranges`.(Drupal and GWT are two different things)

On a serious note

- `GWT is for the client side interactions`. Even when you are using GWT you can still use php(not necessarily java) on the server side. To be frank you can even use Drupal with a little tweaking for server side coding even when using GWT.

GWT is preferred when you have sites with single page, multifunctionality and lots of ajax functions. GWT has lots of built in snippets for calendars, interactive tables and so.

- `Drupal is a CMS and much more than that`. Drupal can be used to build sites quickly and then extend the functionalities and cusomize them according to your needs.